# doxygen: disable PROJECT_NAME in the header

Tags: doxygen

I am documenting a C software using doxygen. I have created a logo for my package, which includes the name of the software and a short synopsis. So I would like to remove the PROJECT_NAME from the header since it really looks odd to have both the logo and the project name, basically, they are the same. I am new to using doxygen, so I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Did you have a look at the possibility to use your own header file in doxygen see: `doxygen -w html header footer stylesheet` and the setting `HTML_HEADER`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using Doxygen 1.9.2. Your suggestion worked, I could remove the PROJECT_NAME from the header by customizing the heder.html file.